# how to get the details of route direction in MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I want to get the direction route detail in `MKMapview`. I mentioned one sample url below. likewise I want but don't want to go next URL. please anyone help, if you know. Is it possible or not in ios?

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { (37.785834), (-122.406417) };
 CLLocationCoordinate2D end = { (48.922499), (-125.507813) };

 NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you to get route from your start to the end point..

In your Viewcontroller.m file use this code..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MapView* mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
    home.name = @"Home";
    home.description = @"Sweet home";
    home.latitude = 37.785834;
    home.longitude = -122.406417;

    Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
    office.name = @"Office";
    office.description = @"Bad office";
    office.latitude = 48.922499;
    office.longitude = -125.507813;


    [mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];
}
```

for more detail about this see the code at this site..
http://code.google.com/p/ashiphone/downloads/detail?name=MapWithRoutes.zip&can=2&q=

If your problem get solved its good otherwise feel free to ask..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i got route from soure to destination clearly.i want the direction detail(summary) from source to destination.(eg:1.go straight and take left,2.take right after 5KM)

Comment: sorry json. that code give only direction between two places. i need detail(summary) of route between two direction.if u know please help.

Comment: @vishnusivabalan  this is exact what you need..you can use google direction API..for more detail and code check this link..https://github.com/volonbolon/Directions               let me know if this doesn't work for you..but i think it works for you..enjoy..

Comment: sorry json.i am new to this mapview and i don't know how  to take the exact coding from the project.(what i need is list of routes ) can u please help me.i think you understand my situation.

Comment: how can i send. can i put in another question or any mail.

Comment: i sent to you.please do some favor for me

Comment: @vishnusivabalan sorry not getting time to edit your code,but check this link   http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/     and let me know..